# Is VHDL a description language for a Boolean circuit or are both concepts unrelated

Tags: programming-languages, circuits

I am looking for a way to translate basic c programs (subset of c or java or some declarative programming language) to a Boolean circuit.

I know that Turing machines are reducible to Boolean circuits in theory, so this should be possible.

However, rather than re-writting things, I know that most EDA tools such as Vivado or ModelSim can take C code and generate VHDL or Verilog... even C++ code.

So would the VHDL code be equivalent to a Boolean circuit?

Comment: In which way is this a computer *science* question?

Comment: There is infinitude of ways to implement this. The simplest case is to take a known processor plus memory (it is your piece of hardware, you can take a gate-level representation of it) and initialize the memory with your program.  You do not map your programs to the circuit as a whole. You just accelerate some parts of it, some operations, which can/worth run in parallel.